# How to get the filled field of java.util.Set <Object> or if the field is empty, return something else?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an Addresses class that is used in two attributes of the Customer class, the first attribute is a simple object to represent the customer's default address and another attribute is a Set <> of addresses that the customer can have.

I need to send the postalCode field to another class. I would like to check in Set <> if there is a filled postalCode, if yes, send this value, otherwise (if there is no filled postalCode within Set <>) then I should send the postalCode value from the default address. How to do this? I tried this way before:

```
Optional.ofNullable(Stream.of(product.getCustomer().getAddresses()).forEach
(i -> i.getPostalCode())).orElse(product.getCustomer().getAddressDefault().getPostalCode()))
```

My classes bellow:

```
public class Customer {

    private Addresses addressDefault;

    private Set<Addresses> addresses;
}

public class Addresses {

    private String postalCode;

    private String city;

    private String state;

    private String country;

}
```

Comment: That requirement doesn't make sense. The postcodes of the various addresses could all be different. You would be sending the wrong postcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 8 streams, you can use `map` to transform an address to its `postalCode`, use `filter` to remove `null` values, and use `findFirst` to get the first non-null postalCode.

`Stream.findFirst` deals with empty streams by returning an optional. To get its value or a default value, use the `Optional.orElse` method.

In code:

```
String postalCode = customer.addresses.stream()
        .map(addresses -> addresses.postalCode)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(customer.addressDefault.postalCode);
```